# Unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, netbook

Hey guys, I have a question.  I have been having problems connecting a new netbook to my network at home.  I have an Asus Eeepc 100HAB.  I have tried to run a repair on the connection, uninstalled and re-installed the network card, made sure all of the drivers are up-to-date as well.  Two caveats:  I have a laptop that I recently switched to a wired connection because it wasn't connecting to the network as well, and the netbook connects to an unsecured network i found just fine, only having a problem getting into my home network.  Passwords are correct, and the computer where the connection originates from is working fine as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try searching SU for `wireless [asus]`: http://superuser.com/search?q=wireless+[asus] and see if one of these doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to connect wirelessly.  Are you using the same encryption (e.g. WPA or WPA2) on the netbook as is on the access point?

It might be nice to find out why your other laptop was also having trouble connecting to that network.  That kind of makes it sound like the trouble is with the wifi access point.  Is it your access point and you are the only one who manages it?  Can you verify that its settings haven't changed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Depending on your router brand type *Private Default IP Address into your address bar and log into your router.
2. Under Device Information scroll down to Wireless LAN and check your Security Mode.
3. Now go to your Wireless Network properties and check that the Security type is the same, also make sure your Encryption type is the same.

*Private Default IP Address:
`192.168.0.1` for D-Link and Netgear models.
`192.168.1.1` for Linksys.
`192.168.2.1` for SMC and Belkin brands.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your internet connection is active? If you have a modem I suggest restarting it and the wireless router.